# How is memory allocated and how is it deallocated?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a class `A` and I create a pointer:

```
A * const q = reinterpret_cast<A * const>(new char[2 * sizeof(A)]);
```

and I have 2 objets:

```
new (q)A;
new (q + 1) A;
```

If I delete the pointer like:

- `delete q;` it is calling one time the destructor of `A`
- `delete[] reinterpret_cast<char *>(q);` there is no call of `~A()`
- `delete q; delete (q+1);` no mather the order is crashing
- `delete [] q` is also crashing

The correct way, I think is like this:

```
q->~A();
q[1].~A();
delete[] reinterpret_cast<char *>(q);
```

Can someone tell me why and what is going on with the memory allocation/deallocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common implementation of `new A` is allocate memory enough for storing 1 `A` object and return the address of allocation (and call constructor for the object after that).

`new A[x]` on the other hand has to track `x` quantity of `A` objects allocated. `x` usually is stored in the first field of allocation, and `new[]` returns the address right after that field (so tha it points to the actual start of array).

In your screwed situation that first field wasn't allocated at all. There is no way `delete[]` can determine `A`'s quantity (It will try, but there will be heap block header at the negative offset of the given pointer instead). So you have to explicitly call destructors for every object and then free memory with `delete` or `delete[]` for any built-in type pointer, otherwise it will try to call destructor.

**Edit**: (Forgot to add)

Heap-allocated arrays of built-in types in usual implementations have no quantity field 'cause they don't need destructors to be called. That is why your `new char[]` `delete [] reinterpret_cast<char *>(q)` differ from `new[]` and `delete[]` for `A`.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can't call `delete` on the instance, that assumes it's going to do the counter of `new` and free the memory. It can't know that you've used placement-`new` to allocate the backing store for the object(s). I think the final snippet is correct, too: run the destructors, and manually free the memory since only you know where it came from.

Comment: So it may come from somewhere else, that is why the `reinterpret_cast<A * const>(new char[2 * sizeof(A)])` is used?

Answer (score 2):

Allocators usually store allocation information next to the node (linked list pointer to next node, size, etc...).

Because of this, you are only allowed to call the deallocator(`delete`) for the same object you allocated. Otherwise you're in UB territory, the deallocator will interpret wrong parts of the memory as the storage for the extra information, and your code will likely crash..

The last example is correct.

<strike>However, I think you could have alignment issues, as the memory was allocated for `char[]` and not an `A`.</strike>

Comment: This means that the whole `char[2*sizeof(A)]` is the memory allocated for just a single `A` object?

Comment: huh? no. I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Memory returned by `new char[X]` (or `unsigned char`) is suitably aligned for any object which size is not greater  than X.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, the last example is correct.**

The rule of thumb is that you can only `delete` what you got from `new` (and only once, of course). The same holds for array versions.

What you got from `new[]` is `char*` and I think it's clear how you'd delete it.

Also, if you use placement-new to construct an object, you're responsible to call the destructors manually (if it's needed).

Comment: @Jarod42 In that it doesn't exits? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What I mean is that we use `delete` for each `new`, but the (non existent) 'placement `delete`' to use for placement `new` is `~T` as syntax, which may seem unnatural.

Comment: It's a bit confusing, I agree, but only because people don't distinguish between *new expression* and (de)allocation functions (`operator new/delete`).